# Starting a Amazon EC2 Free Tier with Ubuntu and Django

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, django, amazon-ebs

I'm planning to begin a Django project that may (or may not) grow to be a pretty big thing. So I wanted to start out well: buy my public DNS (not sure yet if with Google Apps or any other domain provider) and start with a Amazon EC2 server.

So the idea is to have a centralized (git) repo in the server and a Django project running all the time (not yet in production stage, just development). So everybody will work in their local machines and then `push` changes to the centralized repo. Also, we'll be making tests in the development project (probably in the Django admin and checking some views that include database queries).

The question is, does this match the Amazon EC2 "[Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/en/free/)" capacity? or would the activity I'm describing here increase the monthly cost of the server?

Also, we will be developing (thus, making `pulls` and `pushes` to the repo) mostly from South America, but the "target users" (once the project is done) will be from USA, so is it OK if I set the region server to USA (East or West)? or would that also increase the monthly cost of the server?

Finally, I've read a little bit about BitNami's [DjangoStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/djangostack), but I'm not sure it fits my needs. Would it be useful (based on my server description)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wouldn't say *to have a centralized git repository* when actually git is a distributed version control system, any copy of the people you work with is equally valid.

The **AWS Free Usage Tier**, in my opinion, is for getting started with AWS, you will start understanding how it works, how to manage EBS, groups, elastic IPs, basically how to deal with the entire AWS ecosystem.

What about the backend? Will you have a RDBMS? In any case, **you should think more about this as getting started with AWS** and if the application grows you can scale out as much as you need. On the other hand, if you are thinking about AWS just because is *free tier*, you're  going the grown way, at the end you will have to pay either to Amazon or to any other provider.